# How to resize the height of a TabControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml

As the title, I was wondering if it was possible to set some property type: `CanUserResize = true;`
I'm working on a very responsive and actually come up well, but now I want to make sure that the TabControl is somehow possible to be able to increase the height manually, as happens exactly grabbing the edges of the window of `'Window OS or OS X OS'` dragging them up or down. On the net I found nothing, perhaps in WPF is not yet implemented a similar mode ....
There would be a similar road for this purpose should achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a `GridSplitter` to achieve what you're trying to do.

A `GridSplitter` is just one special Control that can be placed inside a `Grid`, and allows the user to grab it and move it up and down (or right or left, depending on whether the splitter is horizontal or vertical) to resize the rows and columns of the `Grid`.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="500" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TabControl x:Name="myTabControl"
                Grid.Row="0" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

You can style the `GridSplitter` any way you want, and use horizontal and vertical splitters at the same time if you like, or even several horizontal or vertical splitters.

EDIT: Generally, the `GridSplitter` figures out automatically whether it's horizontal or vertical, but you can specify it manually using the `ResizeDirection` property (with values `Auto`, `Columns` or `Rows`).

EDIT 2: I've added a `MinHeight` and a `MaxHeight` values to the first `ColumnDefinition` to exemplify how you can prevent the `GridSplitter` from going past some sizes.

Comment: One question: Is possible prevent the GridSplitter to go down? In particular I want that the user can only go up to a maximum height .. but I want set a minimum height for the TabControl so the GridSplitter doesn't must go down..

Comment: I think you can do that by setting `MinHeight` or `MaxHeight` to the `RowDefinition`. The `GridSplitter` should respect those limits.

Comment: I've already tried but not working.. Could you insert this in your example, please?

Comment: Done. Just tried it in a test project and it worked right away, the TabControl shouldn't grow or shrink past the Max or MinHeight you set to its RowDefinition.

Comment: Ah here where wrong! I put the values of limit on GridSplitter as they go on the control! Thank you very much, very good  :D